# Making 'column' ignore lines with fewer tokens than max for pretty display

Tags: linux, command-line, format

I am trying to view a csv file. The csv files contains 2 types of lines:

- lines with say 15 entries (numbers or strings) separated using commas. The number of entries can vary by file, but will be fixed for all such lines in a single file.
- lines containing just one large string and no commas

I was trying to use `column -s, -t` for easy viewing on the command line. The problem is for lines containing just one entry, `column` thinks of it as a member of the first column. This string is big and causes the first column to be pretty big. I am looking for a way to tell `column` to not format rows which have just 1 entry and just print them as is. Is this achievable using `column` or some other utility? I tried using `tr ',' '\t'`, but that didn't align things nicely like `column`.

Example file:

```
asdfasgjfsgadjfasdgjafsdgfkjasgdfkjasgkdasdfagjdghfa
this,is,just,a,siiiiiiiiimple,sample,file
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
wish_column_had_some_more_options
this,is,just,a,siiiiiiiiimple,sample,file
7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

`column` output:

```
asdfasgjfsgadjfasdgjafsdgfkjasgdfkjasgkdasdfagjdghfa
this                                                  is  just  a  siiiiiiiiimple  sample  file
1                                                     2   3     4  5               6       7
wish_column_had_some_more_options
this                                                  is  just  a  siiiiiiiiimple  sample  file
7                                                     6   5     4  3               2       1
```

`tr` output:

```
asdfasgjfsgadjfasdgjafsdgfkjasgdfkjasgkdasdfagjdghfa
this    is  just    a   siiiiiiiiimple  sample  file
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
wish_column_had_some_more_options
this    is  just    a   siiiiiiiiimple  sample  file
7   6   5   4   3   2   1
```

Comment: Maybe you need a pager like `less` w/ ability to chop long lines?

Comment: No. I want to format the output to make it easier to read. I have included the output from `column` and `tr` to make things clearer.